# How mysql error logging works for errors raised in triggers /routines?

Tags: mysql

I have a some triggers setup on a table and when I insert a record it gives following error :

`Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Is there a better way to determine exactly which query is breaking the trigger e.g getting some verbose information about this issue like line no/trigger name ?

I ll appreciate if some one describe how error logging works in mysql. I have enabled error logging already in my.cnf e. g

```
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

[mysqld]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

I cannot share the query or trigger. So I am searching for generic answer to error handling in mysql, not specific to my case.

Comment: did you check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

Comment: @Afghanistan , please see edits